# What is the purpose of the Start Page Redirect Cache registry value?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, windows-registry

Under the `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main` registry key there are a couple of values that I am curious about their intended use. I was looking into setting the default IE home page and saw that it uses the `Start Page` value - and there are a few other values that I was wondering what their purpose is:

- Start Page Redirect Cache
- Start Page Redirect Cache_TIMESTAMP
- Start Page Redirect Cache AcceptLangs

I didn't really find any information on them on TechNet or MSDN. Various pages on the internet claim they can be tampered with by malware that hijacks your home page and search engines and setting them back to something like your desired home page is a good fix. I believe mine is still configured as the Windows 7 default: http://www.msn.com/?ocid=iehp

Anyone with insight into what Internet Explorer uses these values for?